# Why repmgr didn't failover automatically?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, repmgr

### Installation

```
- name: Install repmgr repository
  get_url:
    url: https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/get/10/rpm
    dest: /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr

- name: Install repmgr rpm
  shell: bash /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr

- name: Install repmgr
  yum:
    name: repmgr10
    state: present
```

### [repmgr](https://repmgr.org/) setting

#### node1 - primary

```
$ cat /etc/repmgr/10/repmgr.conf
node_id=1
node_name=node1
conninfo='host=node1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'
data_directory='/var/lib/pgsql/10/data'
failover=automatic
promote_command='repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
log_file='/var/log/repmgr/repmgr.log'
log_level=NOTICE
reconnect_attempts=4
reconnect_interval=5
monitoring_history=yes
```

#### node2 - standby

```
$ cat /etc/repmgr/10/repmgr.conf
node_id=2
node_name=node2
conninfo='host=node2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'
data_directory='/var/lib/pgsql/10/data'
failover=automatic
promote_command='repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
log_file='/var/log/repmgr/repmgr.log'
log_level=NOTICE
reconnect_attempts=4
reconnect_interval=5
monitoring_history=yes
```

### Start their services

```
$ sudo systemctl start repmgr10
```

### Status

```
$ repmgr cluster show
 ID | Name  | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
----+-------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | node1 | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 3        | host=node1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 2  | node2 | standby |   running | node1    | default  | 100      | 3        | host=node2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
```

---

### test

Stop PostgreSQL's service on node1

```
$ sudo systemctl stop postgresql-10
```

It's status can be disconnected. But `node2` can't be `primary` automatically.

After restart PostgreSQL's service on `node1` again, the repmpr cluster status can be the origin again.

Comment: I think `-f /etc/repmgr.conf` is unnecessary.

Comment: possibly a dumb question but have you [configured repmgrd for auto failover](https://repmgr.org/docs/4.0/repmgrd-basic-configuration.html#REPMGRD-AUTOMATIC-FAILOVER-CONFIGURATION)?

Comment: @PeterVandivier A good point, `--upstream-node-id=%n` is also necessary.